# jQuery/Rails: How do I use jQuery to modify submit for multiple forms ending with unique IDs in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a page that creates multiple forms for each object that I had selected on the previous page, and each of these forms has the id "edit_movie_[uid]".  I'm trying to get jQuery to act on submit but right now all it does is make my submit buttons nonresponsive.  In my application.js I have:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
   'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
 })

 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('form[id^="edit_mov"]').submit(function(){
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), null, 'script');
      return false;
   })
 })
```

As the callback for my submit button I just have:

```
alert("jquery works");
```

So an alert box should pop up, but right now none of the buttons do anything and some of them are unclickable.

Comment: Are you using firebug? It sounds like there's a conflicting error in your JS that's halting the entire script. My first guess at least. Is it feasible to comment out a majority of your script, and piece by piece integrate it again?

Comment: You mean that you've attached a click handler to the submit button itself like this?

$('form[id^="edit_mov"] input[type="submit"]').click(function() { alert("jquery works") });

And you're expecting that action to fire the alert? Have you tried checking in a tool like Firebug to see if the POST request is actually happening?

Comment: Haha Trip, good minds think alike. :)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas guys. I actually did know that the script worked because I had tried it on a single form whose id didn't have a uid appended to it and it worked fine. I had to logout and when I restarted my webrick server the script worked. Not sure why it worked, but I'm not going to complain about it either.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're triggering the event in your ready block rather than binding it. You can use bind, or, better yet, delegate. Also, avoid calling $() more than once:

```
$(function() { // Shorthand for $(document).ready()
  //$('form[id^="edit_mov"]').bind('submit', function() {
  $(document).delegate('form[id^="edit_mov"]', 'submit', function() {
    var form = $(this);
    console.log('submit triggered', form);
    $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), null, 'script');
    return false;
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm new to jquery/javascript, so I've just been trying to get the code to work and the "good form" tips much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to be of help. By the way, the delegate function is fairly new, and I think worth understanding well. The idea is that you can allow events on any element to bubble up to the document, so there is only one handler, instead of one for every single matching element. Very powerful.